# Messages are stuck in ActiveMQ Artemis cluster queues

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have a problem with Apache ActiveMQ Artemis cluster queues. Sometimes messages are beginning to pile up in the particular cluster queues. It usually happens 1-4 times per day and mostly on production (it was only one time for last 90 days when it has happened on one of the test environments).

These messages are not delivered to consumers on other cluster brokers until we restart cluster connector (or entire broker).

The problem looks related to [ARTEMIS-3809](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3809).

Our setup is: 6 servers in one environment (3 pairs of master/backup servers). Operating system is Linux (Red Hat).

We have tried to:

- upgrade from 2.22.0 to 2.23.1
- increase `minLargeMessageSize` on the cluster connectors to `1024000`

The messages are still being stuck in the cluster queues.

Another problem that I tried to configure `min-large-message-size` as it written in documentation (in `cluster-connection`), but it caused errors at start (`broker.xml` did not pass validation with xsd), so it was only option to specify `minLargeMessageSize` in the URL parameters of connector for each cluster broker. I don't know if this setting has effect.

So we had to make a script which checks if messages are stuck in the cluster queues and restarts cluster connector.

How can we debug this situation?
When the messages are stuck, nothing wrong is written to the log (no errors, no stacktraces etc.).
Which logging level (for what classes) should we enable to debug or trace level to find out what happens with the cluster connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can remedy the situation by setting this on your `cluster-connection`:

```xml
<producer-window-size>-1</producer-window-size>
```

See [ARTEMIS-3805](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3805) for more details.

Generally speaking, moving message around the cluster via the `cluster-connection`, while convenient, isn't terribly efficient (much less so for "large" messages). Ideally you would have a sufficient number of clients on each node to consume the messages that were originally produced there. If you don't have that many clients then you may want to re-evaluate the size of your cluster as it may actually *decrease* overall message throughput rather than increase it.

If you're just using 3 HA pairs in order to establish a quorum for replication then you should investigate the recently added [pluggable quorum voting](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#pluggable-quorum-vote-replication-configurations) which allows integration with a 3rd party component (e.g. ZooKeeper) for leader election eliminating the need for a quorum of brokers.

Comment: And we planned to build a new cluster with pluggable quorum, but I don't remember if this feature is already production-ready.

Comment: So does that mean you have 3 HA pairs specifically to establish a quorum for replication?

Comment: As far as production readiness goes, the configuration is still subject to change technically speaking although I think that's unlikely at this point. I strongly encourage you to test it out in your environment and report any issues you have with it. Open Source projects like ActiveMQ only get better when folks participate.

Comment: Yes, this cluster with 3 pairs was made mainly for this purpose (to have 3 members for quorum).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I will return later when I check if `producer-window-size` setting was helpful.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the new `producer-window-size` value?

Comment: I have configured this setting on production servers about 2-3 days ago and everything is ok. We need more time to check, but I think it helped.