# ActiveMQ Artemis $.artemis.internal.sf sometimes building up messages

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

At random times the cluster bridge queue `$.artemis.internal.sf` is building up messages as if the bridge was stuck. Other queues are happily receiving messages and they are consumed as expected, even under load.

The setup in production is as follow:

- ActiveMQ Artemis version is 2.22.0 running on Java 11 (no excessive GC observed or not at buildup times).
- 2 "levels" of clusters, say one for the "surface" and one for the "deep" stuff.
  2 vmware VMs for each level in the same security tag/vlan (I don't have access to that and changing it might not be an option).
- "Surface" VMs are artm and arts, "deep" VMs are artim and artis.
- Each of these levels contains 3 clusters (cluster-1, cluster-2 and cluster-3 for the example, real ones have different names but I'm not allowed to disclose them) with 2 masters and 2 slaves each, grouped in pairs masterA with slaveA and masterB with slaveB (using group name in the ha-policy

```
artm has masterA-S1, masterA-S2, masterA-S3 and slaveB-S1, slaveB-S2, slaveB-S3
arts has masterB-S1, masterB-S2, masterB-S3 and slaveA-S1, slaveA-S2, slaveA-S3
```

```
artim has masterA-D1, masterA-D2, masterA-D3 and slaveB-D1, slaveB-D2, slaveB-D3
artis has masterB-D1, masterB-D2, masterB-D3 and slaveA-D1, slaveA-D2, slaveA-D3
```

- Ports are adapted to avoid collision and all works nicely.
- On the "deep" clusters, we have apps that can only have one consumer so we use message redistribution since we don't exactly know on which of the 2 masters it will connect to (connectionFactories and providerUrl are set ok).
- The configuration of the 3 clusters in a given level are similar.

Cluster connections are as follow

masterA-D1

```xml
<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="cluster-D1">
      <connector-ref>connector-D1-master-a</connector-ref>
      <check-period>1000</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>20001</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>2000</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
         <static-connectors>
            <connector-ref>connector-D1-slave-a</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>connector-D1-master-b</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>connector-D1-slave-b</connector-ref>
         </static-connectors>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

masterB-D1

```xml
<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="cluster-D1">
      <connector-ref>connector-D1-master-b</connector-ref>
      <check-period>1000</check-period>
      <connection-ttl>20001</connection-ttl>
      <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
      <reconnect-attempts>1</reconnect-attempts>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <notification-interval>2000</notification-interval>
      <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
      <static-connectors>
         <connector-ref>connector-D1-slave-b</connector-ref>
         <connector-ref>connector-D1-master-a</connector-ref>
         <connector-ref>connector-D1-slave-a</connector-ref>
      </static-connectors>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

The surface level has a total of approx 400 queues (anycast) and approx 450 for the deep lever (anycast as well).

The bridge between masterA and masterB is correctly connected. The logs confirm that.

On a daily basis the whole system handles approx 8-9 million messages.

We tried to log the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl` class hoping to see `"Bridge retrying connection #` (which would have indicated a connection issue and required to increase the reconnect-attempts) but no luck.

When buildup happens, other instances still behave nicely.

We just set the reconnect-attempts to `-1` (unlimited retry). Wait and see if it helps but I doubt it.

We set alerts on the message count on the bridge queue so when the buildup happens we can restart the instances and restore the bridge consumer, but that's not ideal since it disturbs our service.

No other bridge is configured.

The buildup does not necessarily happens on heavy load, nor on high uptime. We've seen buildup with a 7 days uptime whereas we have other instances with 35+ days of uptime with no issue and same kind of usage/trafic.

We can't reproduce it. That's why I'm giving as much info as I can.

I can provide more details if required.

I found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165421/messages-are-stuck-in-activemq-artemis-cluster-queues), but I'm not sure it's related. Although we do send some large messages that's not what we send the most, but I have to assume, given our setup, large messages can be forwarded by the bridge. We have at most 50 large messages a day on the whole system.

Comment: not yet, we have to be sure this is the issue (we can’t modify the production that easily ;) )
I noticed the doc states -1 is the default value for this parameter. do we still have to set it explicitely?

Comment: well, this one says 1MB https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.22.0/clusters.html and that https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.22.0/configuration-index.html#cluster-connection-type says -1... the code seems to say -1 (org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.config.ActiveMQDefaultConfiguration#DEFAULT_BRIDGE_PRODUCER_WINDOW_SIZE is -1). I’m confused :/

Comment: sorry, old reference from my IDE. -1 is in 2.16, 1024 * 1024 in 2.22 so we should set -1 indeed, but the doc still confuses me

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. we’ll give our preproduction a try and see what we can do. I’ll keep you posted

Comment: Any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a combination of factors at work here.

The default `producer-window-size` on `cluster-connection` used to be `-1`, but it was changed to `1048576` (i.e. 1MiB) in 2.22.0 via [ARTEMIS-3805](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3805). To be clear, the ["Clusters" chapter](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.22.0/clusters.html) in the documentation was updated with this new default, but the ["Configuration Index" chapter](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.22.0/configuration-index.html#cluster-connection-type) was missed.

However, when 2.22.0 was released there was an unknown bug with flow-control which can cause the bridge to get stuck when moving large messages from one node to another. [This bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4003) wasn't resolved until 2.26.0 via [ARTEMIS-4003](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4003).

Therefore, I believe you can solve this issue one of two ways:

1. Stay on 2.22.0 and set this on your `cluster-connection` in `broker.xml`:

   ```xml
   <producer-window-size>-1<producer-window-size>
   ```
2. Upgrade to 2.26.0.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue on our preprod environment using a few large messages.
applying your recommendation regarding the producer-window-size solved the case after a broker restart despite the logs saying the configuration was reloaded.
We're planning on applying the settings on production tonight but AFAICT we have a working solution, so thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm using version 2.27.1 and seems I'm experiencing the same behavior. Is it possible that the problem is back? Tried to add the <producer-window-size>-1</producer-window-size> to <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">, but this seems to not be a valid configuration. On https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.27.1/clusters.html seems to still exist.

Comment: Realized that order matters...will check tomorrow if the problem disappears with that config. Thanks

Comment: Using either 2.26.0 (or later) or `<producer-window-size>-1</producer-window-size>` I've not seen this particular error. This question has been answered so if you have additional trouble ask a new one. Thanks!